# ¿Cómo saber si un valor en un diccionario es un subconjunto de otro valor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Con este diccionario inicial:

```
{1: ["a", "b", "c"], 2: ["c", "a", "d", "e", "f"]}
```

¿Cómo puedo preguntar si alguno de los elementos de `["a", "b", "c"]` se encuentra en `["c", "a", "d", "e", "f"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes iterar y preguntar:

```
>>> d = {1: ["a", "b", "c"], 2: ["c", "a", "d", "e", "f"]}
>>> for x in d[1]:
...   if x in d[2]:
...     print x
... 
a
c
>>>
```

Entonces ya sabes que `"a"` y `"c"` se encuentran en `["c","a","d","e","f"]`.

Otra forma es usando `filter`:

```
>>> d = {1:["a","b","c"], 2:["c","a","d","e","f"]}
>>> filter(lambda x: x in d[2], d[1])
['a', 'c']
>>>
```

En Python 3 `filter` te devuelve un iterador así que lo único que tienes que hacer es convertirlo a una lista:

```
>>> d = {1: ["a", "b", "c"], 2: ["c", "a", "d", "e", "f"]}
>>> filter(lambda x: x in d[2], d[1])
<filter object at 0x7f51193c3d68>
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x in d[2], d[1]))
['a', 'c']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si solo quieres saber si algún elemento de la lista está presente en la otra puedes usar `any` (que implementa *short-circuit*) junto a un generador con `in` para comprobar la pertenencia:

```
>>> dic = {1:["a","b","c"], 2:["c","a","d","e","f"]}
>>> any(e in dic[2] for e in dic[1])
True

>>> dic = {1:["a","b","c"], 2:["h","g","d","e","f"]}
>>> any(e in dic[2] for e in dic[1])
False
```

Si además quieres los elementos comunes puedes usar una lista o generador por compresión:

```
>>> dic = {1:["a","b","c"], 2:["c","a","d","e","f"]}
>>> [e for e in dic[1] if e in dic[2]]
['a', 'c']
```

No obstante, si tus listas son relativamente grandes, más aún si el elemento común no existe o está al final de los iterables, es mucho más eficiente usar intersección de conjuntos para aprovechar la eficiencia de las búsquedas y comprobaciones de pertenencia en tablas hash, crear dos nuevos objetos compensa en este caso:

```
>>> dic = {1:["a","b","c"], 2:["c","a","d","e","f"]}
>>> bool(set(dic[1]) & set(dic[2]))
True

>>> dic = {1:["a","b","c"], 2:["h","g","d","e","f"]}
>>> bool(set(dic[1]) & set(dic[2]))
False
```

La intersección de conjuntos retorna otro conjunto con los elementos comunes presentes al mismo tiempo en todos ellos:

```
>>> dic = {1:["a","b","c"], 2:["c","a","d","e","f"]}
>>> set(dic[1]) & set(dic[2])
{'c', 'a'}
```

Si quieres saber si todos los elementos de la lista de la clave 1 entán en la lista de la clave 2 es también muy útil el uso de conjuntos:

```
>>> dic = {1:["a","b","c"], 2:["c","a","d","e","f"]}
>>> set(dic[1]) <= set(dic[2])
False

>>> dic = {1:["a","b","c"], 2:["c","a","b","e","f"]}
>>> set(dic[1]) <= set(dic[2])
True
```